# Gradle Plugin Eclipse - Cannot accept license

Tags: eclipse, gradle, ubuntu-13.10

I am unable to accept the license agreement for the Gradle plugin in Eclipse.

[image]

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: I meet the same problem. How did you fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there was bug with check box control.
You should have shared Java, Eclipse, OS exact versions.

Have you tried clicking "I do not" and then "I accept" again?